# How can I see the harddisk temperature file directly?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, bash, script, temperature

I am a general user using x86-64 Ubuntu.

I make a bash script to do a temperature check There is a dubbing and I ask you a question.

How can I see the harddisk temperature file directly like cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp? (not like hddtemp, smartctl)

Is that a silly question?

Comment: they say that in linux "everything is a file"   though I don't really trust them, maybe it isn't.. See https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-hard-drive-temperature.html    there's a command to output hdd temperature from the hdd's SMART data, but that seems to be not a file.

Comment: thx, but i know that. just wondering... 'where is the harddisk temperature file?'

Comment: I don't know.. I hope somebody does.. Another way you might be able to get an answer is  to ask on a programming language forum how to do it in C and then after that, how does C do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "hardware temperature file" for the harddisk. Things like  `sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` are not real files, they are interfaces to the kernel, and when you read from them, what happens is that the kernel executes code that reads the temperature from the sensors.

Now the harddisk doesn't have a special kernel driver to read the temperature, so there's no corresponding file in `/sys`. What you can do instead is to use a special protocol ([SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)) that uses the normal disk communication accessible from a program e.g. via `/dev/sd*` to interrogate the microcontroller on the harddisk, which, among other things, can read the current temperature.

So there's no other way to get this information except using a program like `smartctl` or `hddtemp`.

Comment: You also don't really want to be wasting precious resources on the hard disk controller constantly polling it for temperature when what you really want to be doing is transferring data. On high bandwidth busses and devices where the code is already running (such as reading CPU temp sensors) it is less of an issue as it is reading a register in the current device, but on a hard disk you could be effectively blocking a read or write for several milliseconds in order to get the temperature.

Comment: so...what can i do? uses smartctl or hddtemp? and Then I will ask another question. If hdd only has to go through s.m.a.r.t that is different from the kernel reference, do you have to proceed with installing hddtemp and smartctl separately to all OS's? (In ubuntu it was not the default installation), any other ways? thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is just to periodically call `smartctl` and `hddtemp`, and yes, you have to install them (which shouldn't be an issue).Alternatively, you can of course extract the code and write your own program or plugin to get this information.